# Mongodb - query with '$or' gives no results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

There is extremely weird thing happening on my database. I have a query:

`db.Tag.find({"word":"foo"})`

this thing matches one object. it's nice.

Now, there's second query

`db.Tag.find({$or: [{"word":"foo"}]})`

and the second one does not give any results.

There's some kind of magic I obviously don't understand :( What is wrong in second query?

in theory, `$or` requires two or more parameters, so I can fake it with:

`db.Tag.find({$or: [{"word":"foo"},{"word":"foo"}]})`

but still, no results.

Comment: what exactly is the point of that query? does db.Tag.find({$or: [{"word":"foo"}, {"word":"bar"}]}) fail as well?

Comment: Your query as it stands, is perfectly fine. It should work, if only you haven't done any mistake somewhere else.

Comment: edited question, double 'or' fails the same :(

Comment: could you please cut and paste the output from mongo shell showing both queries and their output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okaay, server admin installed mongodb from debian repo. Debian repo had 1.4.4 version of mongodb, aandd looks like `$or` is simply not yet supported out there :P

Answer (score 0):

Your second query is perfectly fine, and it should work. Though the docs says, that `$or` performs logical operation on array of two or more expression, but it would work for single expression also.

Here's a sample that you can see, and try out, to get it to work: -

```
> db.col.insert({"foo": "Rohit"})
> db.col.insert({"foo": "Aman", "bar": "Rohit"})
>
> db.col.find({"foo": "Rohit"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ed6bb1a401d9b4576417f7"), "foo" : "Rohit" }
> db.col.find({$or: [{"foo": "Rohit"}]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("50ed6bb1a401d9b4576417f7"), "foo" : "Rohit" }
```

So, as you can see, both your query when used for my collection works fine. So, there is certainly something wrong somewhere else. Are you sure you have data in your collection?

Comment: as I said, first query finds one object, like it should be. so I'm sure there is some data.

Comment: @Bugari.. Well, I have added the test I did, with your query, and the result I got is also there. So, I can't say that it should not work. And I can't comment on why it's not working in your case. At least not with so much information you currently have given.